# Where can one find the native GMF XML format documentation?

Tags: xml, eclipse-gmf

I'm directly reading GMF XML files and creating SVG with considerable success. However, there may be edge cases not covered by reverse engineer of my very extensive set of examples.

Does anyone know where one can obtain the XML schema or other documentation for the **native GMF XML**? For techical reasons I can't use anything from the Eclipse world.